# Use another Git project as module

Tags: java, git, gradle

I have two gradle projects: the larger system and the smaller pre-existing (our internal code, nontheless) connector library, which I want to use in it. Both have their own git repos on bitbucket, but there's no artifactory to just pull the library as a dependancy. I've tried using [git sumbodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), but couldn't get it quite right: I don't want to mix two projects' `src` folders, but without that I can't import submodule classes. How do I do this using gradle and/or git?

Comment: Can you add a link to the *pre-existing library*?

Comment: It's our internal project, I'll clarify this in the question, thanks.